# what is difference between s3 web static content or web server

Tags: amazon-s3, webserver

I am little confused for a web server or s3 static web content, what should be good, Please explain what is advantages of the web server and what is disadvantages of the web server as well as s3.

Comment: Please explain your use-case and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi John, I want to know that, how much con-currency s3 can serve using web static content, and why should we use s3 as web static web content.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is highly scaled. It supports some of the world's largest websites.

Data stored on Amazon S3 is replicated to multiple data centres, making the data highly resilient.

It is commonly used to store and serve **static web content** (eg style sheets, images, scripts) and is also used by companies around the world to store data for internal consumption (known as *data lakes*).

Compared to a web server, it is much simpler to use, more reliable, does not require engineering support (it's a managed service) and is likely to be cheaper, too.

However, please note that it only stores and serves *static content*. It cannot provide any back-end logic for applications. You would use a server or AWS Lambda functions to provide that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the support John Rotenstein.